# Error: Python packaging tool 'setuptools' not found

Tags: python, pycharm, setuptools, python-poetry

I have a poetry project that is not using setuptools

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.9,<3.11"
opencv-python = "^4.7.0.68"
tensorflow-macos = "^2.11.0"
tensorflow-metal = "^0.7.0"
```

but I keep getting this error in pycharm. Command from screenshot:

```
/Users/mc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/besafe-_8yAv-v6-py3.9/bin/Python /Users/mc/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/223.8214.51/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/packaging_tool.py list
```

It just pops up without any action from my side. It seems like PyCharm is doing some execution under the hood but I do not know what is it.

I do not understand how am I supposed to fix this?

[image]

Comment: What's the executed command? -- You should always avoid posting screenshots of text (or code), and copy-paste the text into your question instead.

Comment: No command is executed it just popup at some times. I think PyCharm is doing sth underneeth but I do not know what.

Comment: @sinoroc just added full command to the post. PyCharm is probably doing sth expected but I do not know what ;)

Comment: Track the PyCharm issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-48909/PyCharm-assumes-the-presence-of-setuptools-and-pip

Answer (score 16):

While it seems that this requires a fix from the PyCharm team, an interim solution is to install `setuptools` as a development dependency,

new version (thanks @milonimrod)

```bash
poetry add --group dev setuptools
```

old version,

```bash
poetry add --dev setuptools
```

Comment: I would recommend using `poetry add --group dev setuptools`  as `--dev` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the only solution was to uninstall PyCharm and install the newest version. All problems disappeared. The problems started when I began using Python 3.12 instead of Python 3.11. Unfortunately, I don't remember the version of the old PyCharm that made problems.

Comment: I am not sure if it's the only solution, but for me it was for sure the quickest.
Updating from 3.10 to 3.12 was the trigger for me.

Comment: Thanks. Got that error during Poetry env creation for Python 3.12 installed via pyenv. Upgrading from PyCharm 2023.1.3 to 2023.3.3 solved it.

Comment: Not work for me. I've updated my PyCharm CE to 2023.3.5 from 2023.2 but still have the same issue.

Comment: @johnnyasd12 what i recommend is uninstall old version and install new one

Answer (score -3):

Check if pip is installed and is added to path variable. It seems like pip is missing, Download pip and try again.

Linux:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Follow this documentation for more.
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

```
pip install setuptools
```

Comment: I'm using `poetry` not pip. Why I should install pip just to fix this bug? Is Pycharm using it under the hood?

Comment: Try install setuptools using pip and check if the error is resolved.

Comment: so hater, he is trying to help